# Scrollbars & resizable are not appearing in onclick="window.open"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open a new window using onclick="window.open" for some reason the scrollbars & resizable Are not working in IE11,and it's working fine in but do work fine Chrome.

```
<div class="editor-field editorholder" style="height: auto;">
<a href="@Url.Action("QuickView", "Home", new { id = @Model.UniqueKey })" class="btn-mvc" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=0','location=0','status=0','menubar=0,','scrollbars=yes','resizable=yes','width=100','height=100'); return false;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried with 'scrollbars=1','resizable=1' but no changies..any help please...thank you

Comment: `'location=0','status=0','menubar=0,','scrollbars=yes','resizable=yes','width=100','height=100'` should be one string, something like `'location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=100,height=100'`.

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popupwindow', 'width=1280  height=800 resizable scrollbars menubar=yes'); return false;"
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add both:

```
scrolling=yes, scrollbars=yes
```